# modify iphone static library (.a file)

Tags: iphone, static-libraries

how can i modify (just only change url) my static library file (.a
 file)? in fact i can see url string when i open with textmate editor
 and then change then save. but it gives this error:

error which i take;

```
ld: in /Users/ysnky/iPhonePro/MySDKTestApp/../../Desktop/iPhoneMySDK/MySDK.a, file is universal but does not contain a(n) i386 slice
```

url which i would like to change;

`static NSString* baseUrl = @"http://127.0.0.1:8080/SDKProxyServer/secure/";`

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't do it like that!

But if you really want to edit binary files try [0xED](http://www.suavetech.com/0xed/0xed.html)

Remember to keep the length of the file. This meaning that you can only enter an url with the same length or shorter (padding with zeros).

Comment: if new url lenght is much more than the old one, what should i do?

Comment: you could try to shorten it with some url shortening service like tinyurl.com or make a redirect on your own server...